# what is type means

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```
STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Error_Code) 
       FROM 
           (SELECT Connection_type, Error_Code, Count 
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                     Connection_Type, error_code, count(*) AS count,
                     row_number() over(partition by Connection_Type order by count(*) desc) as ROWNUM 
                 FROM
                     Staging 
                 WHERE
                     TransactionDate >= convert(varchar, getdate() -1, 111) 
                     AND Status != 'Deliver'
                 GROUP BY
                     Connection_Type, error_code) a 
            WHERE
                rownum <= 10) c
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

what does "TYPE" means?what is significant of using TYPE

Comment: Read the docs?!?!?!?  [`TYPE` directive in FOR XML queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a value typed as XML.

A common alternative that does not use this and just returns directly as string is below.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Error_Code)
              FROM   (VALUES('FOO & BAR'),
                            ('1 < 4 ') ) c(Error_Code)
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

But this does not handle XML entitisation correctly and returns

```
[FOO &amp; BAR],[1 &lt; 4 ]
```

Returning the XML datatype and calling `.value` on it correctly returns

```
[FOO & BAR],[1 < 4 ]
```